# PHP import CSV with utf-8 accents

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, import

I am having issues importing a CSV file which contains (french) names with accents in them... when ever they are imported the accent do not display properly example

félix turns into fŽlix

the file is created by hand and then imported into PHP.

I have tried both utf8_encode() and utf8_decode() and nether function will convert the chars so they can be viewed properly.

my question is how can i get this to render properly... convert char-set.. etc

I believe the text is encoded in Cp850 based on other questions i've seen on here. I am using fgetcvs() to get the contents.

Comment: What code are you currently using to read the file? fopen/fgetcvs/etcetera?

Comment: Try saying `iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 2):

Set Header Information before you output as UTF

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$log = file_get_contents("log.csv");
echo utf8_encode($log);
```

Output

```
félix
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try [iconv](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)() function

Comment: print iconv("Cp850", "UTF-8", $text); // prints fÃ„lix

Comment: Seems like UTF-8. Try to output it inside a page that has `<meta>` tag that declares page encoding to be utf-8. http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is late answer but may be helpful for those who are still searching for solution. This is just a tweak. Not always recommended .

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv');
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 with BOM
readfile("filename.csv");
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this on upload

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir .$target_file)) {
      $log = file_get_contents($target_dir .$target_file);
      file_put_contents($target_dir .$target_file, utf8_encode($log));
```